# C++ warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I need help with fixing the program. It is not running. I keep getting the warning control reaches end of non void function. I dont know how to fix it. Please help me. The program is suppose to find the volume or the surface area of a sphere. I get the warning on the last 2 }

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

char s = '\0';
const char SENTINEL = 's';

float radius, answer;

void get_radius (float&);
float surface_area (float);
float volume (float);
float cross_section (float);

const float PI = 3.14;

int main()
{
cout << "This program will let you input the radius of a sphere to     find its volume or surface area." << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter 'v' for volume or 'a' for surface area of a sphere" << endl;
cout << "'s' to stop" << endl;
cin >> s;
while (s != SENTINEL)
{
    get_radius (radius);

    if(s == 'V')
    {
        volume (radius);
    }
    else if(s == 'A')
    {
        surface_area (radius);
    }

    cout << "Enter 'v' for volume or 'a' for surface area of a sphere" << endl;
    cout << "'s' to stop" << endl;
    cin >> s;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
void get_radius (float& radius)
{
cout << "Please enter the radius of the sphere: " << endl;
cin >> radius;
}

float volume (float radius){
float answer;
answer = 4.0/3.0 * PI * pow (radius, 3);
cout << "The volume is: " << answer << endl;
}
float surface_area (float radius){
float answer;
answer =  4.0 * PI * pow(radius, 2);
cout << "The surface area is: " << answer << endl;
}
```

Comment: Neither `volume()` nor `surface_area()` `return` anything.

Comment: how can i fix it then. I tried return 0; but it doesn't work

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works, then build up. If you had done it that way, you would have known exactly where the problem is, and a quick look in the textbook would have shown you how to write a function that returns something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function declaration must match what you are returning. You have to make sure you are returning values from functions that are declared that they are returning something.

volume() and surface_area() are printing things with cout but are not returning anything.

```
float volume (float radius){
    float answer;
    answer = 4.0/3.0 * PI * pow (radius, 3);
    cout << "The volume is: " << answer << endl;
    return answer;
}

float surface_area (float radius){
    float answer;
    answer =  4.0 * PI * pow(radius, 2);
    cout << "The surface area is: " << answer << endl;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: what can i do to fix it. I tried return answer; but that did nothing

Comment: You'd need to add that to the end of BOTH of your float functions.

Comment: I tried that. I dont think it needs to return anything. It just need to let me input a new radius

Comment: It was suppose to be for another variable, but my teacher said it wasnt needed. i forgot to get rid of, i got rid of it now

Comment: When i did the return answer; for both, the warning is gone, but it doesnt give me an answer when i input the radius. It just repeats the press v or a

Comment: good, that is what we expected. Mark the answer as correct if this was your problem

Comment: but it doesnt give me an answer. It just loops back to the start and asks for v a or s

Comment: Your code checks for capital V and capital A while your cout statments say lowecase. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Edit your code with if(s=='V'||s=='v') same for A .

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the type of a function, you need to return a value of that type.  For example, your function:

```
    float volume (float radius) {}
```

Needs a return statement returns a value of type float.

If you don't need the function to actually return something, then declare it void to let the compiler know that.  In this case:

```
    void volume (float radius)
```

Just be careful, since void functions must NOT return a value (they can use a bare return statement, though).

Note also that potential paths which skips the return statement can trigger this error.  For example, I could have this function:

```
    int veryBadFunction(int flag)
    {
        if (flag == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

In this case, even though there IS a return statement in the function, it gets skipped any time the value of flag is something other than '1'.  This is why the error message is worded *control reaches...*

Comment: I dont need it to return any variable, but i need it to loop and let me start over without stopping unless i press s